# How to make a "title" a link

Tags: 7

Building a content type "news headlines." I want the title to be the headline and I want that headline to link to a outside URL that has the full story. This node-summary could then appear on the home page and in a view and not link to the node but to the outside story. I can make a link that does that but cannot figure out how to make the title do this.

Comment: how you're presenting the news headlines? in a view?

Comment: you mean link to external website

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is implementing a preprocess function for the node.tpl.php file, and alter the content of `$variables['node_url']`, which is the variable the template file uses when rendering the title.

```
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if (!$page): ?>
    <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
```

You should first verify `$variables['page']` is not `TRUE`, since that means the node is being shown in its own page, which is not what happens, for example, when the node is shown as teaser in the front page or in a view.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, in the **Fields** section, click on the **Content: Title** field. In the **Rewrite Results** field-set, check **Rewrite the output of this field**. There you can override the output of the field with custom text, replacement tokens, etc. You can also Output the field as a link and set the required link path.